# How to add space between DIVs?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a WordPress generated page where I want to place AdSense below the header of the page.  See image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTOQB.jpg

I want to create some white space between the header and the AdSense ad.  I've tried adding margin-top and padding to the div that contains the AdSense ad (as noted below) - all to no avail.

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5px; padding: 13px 0 10px 0;">
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "**************";
    google_ad_slot = "**************";
```

What do I have to do provide some white space between the header and the AdSense ad?

P.S. The site is http://phoneswithwindows.com/

Comment: Glad to see my AdBlock is still going strong!

Comment: I have it too, but the internet connection isn't gonna pay for itself :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

put in your css

```
#access {
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: `margin:0 auto 5px` in this case (since there already is a `margin:0 auto` declaration present).

Comment: Those two are very well combined. It doesn't matter if they're 2 properties (being `margin` first and `margin-bottom` after).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Using just margin-bottom leave the other margin eventually set into other css untouched.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943560/html-alignment-issue-in-one-machine-only-both-ie8 ?

Answer (score 3):

I added `margin-top: 5px` on the `<ins>` element inside the div and it work. If you could add an id to the div you use this css rule:

```
div#adds > ins{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Child selectors (`>`) don't work in IE6. This may or may not be an issue, depending on the OP's support needs, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `margin-bottom` to the div with id "access"

Answer (score 1):

Your `#access` div has `float:left;` on it, so you will need to add `clear:left` (or `clear:both`) on the div containing the ad, so they don't overlap.

If you look at your page with Firebug, or the developer tools in your favorite browser, you can see that your ad div actually sits above and layered below your header divs, and when you add `clear: both`, it will move down to where it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the following

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

after the header div?

This way the header float (if it had a float) is cleared and the Ad div below should now utilise the padding